# Create Iterable and pass in values directly

Tags: java, android, arrays, wildcard, iterable

In an app I am working on, I want to return an Iterable or a subclass of Iterable and pass in the values directly. So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
private CustomClass valueOne;
private CustomClass valueTwo;

public Iterable<? extends CustomClass> children() {
    return Array.asList(valueOne, valueTwo);
}
```

The thing is, `asList` doesn't seem to work. Is there anything like this that I could use? I've been searching but I can't seem to find anything that works in my case.

Comment: there is a method Arrays.asList takes array as input and returns list

Comment: Arrays.asList always takes n number of homogeneous elements and returns the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
Array.asList
```

to

```
Arrays.asList
```

`asList` method is available on `Arrays` class not in `Array`

```
List<CustomClass> list= Arrays.asList(new CustomClass[]{valueOne,valueTwo});
```